# GridView items hidden when HeaderTemplate specified

Tags: windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I have a grid view like so:

```
<GridView ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource GroupedMatches}}" 
              SelectionMode="None"
              ItemClick="OnItemClicked"
              IsItemClickEnabled="True"
              Grid.Row="4"
              Grid.Column="1">
        <GridView.GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
            </GroupStyle>
        </GridView.GroupStyle>
    </GridView>
```

`GroupedMatches` is a CollectionViewSource in the page:

```
<CollectionViewSource x:Name="GroupedMatches" 
                      Source="{Binding Matches}" 
                      IsSourceGrouped="True" 
                      ItemsPath="Matches" />
```

Its backing view model is a class with Name and Matches properties where Matches is an IEnumerable.

When the above is rendered with three items spanning two groups, only two of the items are rendered. If I remove the GridView.GroupStyle then all three items are rendered as expected. Does anyone know what might be causing the item to be culled when headers are present?

Edit: Following up I have discovered that the second group (in which items are not appearing as expected) seems to have its size match the first group. So if the first group has two items in it the second group will show two items. If the first group has three items the first group will show three, and so on. For now I have opted to change the layout to more closely reflect the default grid layout mentioned by Filip, but have not been able to determine why the two groups' sizes are linked.

Comment: so your data model includes a collection called Matches and that collection itself includes another collection called Matches (in addition to a Name property)?  Your CollectionViewSource shows Matches as both the binding Source AND as an ItemsPath into that Source, implying Matches at two different levels of the ViewModel.  Are you getting any binding errors in the Debug windows when you run?

Comment: Hi Jim, thanks for clarifying. It is confusing, but the ItemSource "Matches" has a property in turn named "Matches". There are no binding errors being reported in debug view.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Alex (I believe we'd met before). In addition to what Jim said (does each of your Matches represent an object with a Name and another nested Matches property?) you might run into an issue where if you don't specify the `GroupStyle.Panel` - you will get a default `StackPanel` which might get some items in your grouped collection clipped. When you create a default "Grid App (XAML)"-template based application - you get the following definition of the group panel:

```
<GroupStyle.Panel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <VariableSizedWrapGrid
            Orientation="Vertical"
            Margin="0,0,80,0" />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</GroupStyle.Panel>
```

Now if you comment that out - your groups will change from this

[image: GridView with GroupStyle defined]

to this

[image: GridView with GroupStyle undefined]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Filip, I tried making your changes and found that they did not resolve the issue. In the end however I opted to hew more closely to the stock grid view you mention to work around the problem.